# foreach -> array -> json - Group them together

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm trying to get an output in json, but currently I have a to either group them together, or remove the key in the json output.

```
$output = array();
foreach ($data->results() as $data) {
  $output[]['id'] = $data->id;
  $output[]['userid'] = $data->userid;
  $output[]['title'] = $data->title;
}
echo json_encode($output);
```

This current code will out following, but they don't group in id, userid and title as I would like it to do.

> [{"id":"31"},{"userid":"1"},{"title":"Test 1"},{"id":"52"},{"userid":"1"},{"title":"Test 2"},{"id":"53"},{"userid":"1"},{"title":"Test 3"},{"id":"58"},{"userid":"1"},{"title":"Test 4"}]

I then tried to do it in another way, by giving the array a key to group them, but my problem is that the system dont regonize the code then, if they have the ID as key.

```
$output = array();
foreach ($data->results() as $data) {
  $id = $data->id;
  $output[$id]['id'] = $data->id;
  $output[$id]['userid'] = $data->userid;
  $output[$id]['title'] = $data->title;
}
```

> {"31":{"id":"31","userid":"1","title":"Test 1"},"52":{"id":"52","userid":"1","title":"Test 2"},"53":{"id":"53","userid":"1","title":"Test 3"},"58":{"id":"58","userid":"1","title":"Test 4"}}

I would like it to remove the key which I have input. Currently I can't really think of a way to do it.

---

As Anant requested:
The output for $data->results() is all the informations from my database in a table. The problem is that I would like to change either the array $data->results(), but could not find a method for that, so choose to play around with this method instead shown above.

> [{"id":"31","userid":"1","title":"Test 1"},{"id":"52","userid":"1","title":"Test 2"},{"id":"53","userid":"1","title":"Test 3"},{"id":"58","userid":"1","title":"Test 4"}]

Comment: 1. please show us by printing `$data->results();` what it have? 2. what is your expected outcome look like-show that also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create the new array in one step

```
$output = array();
foreach ($data->results() as $data) {
  $output[] = array(
    'id' => $data->id,
    'userid' => $data->userid,
    'title' => $data->title);
}
echo json_encode($output);
```

Comment: Amazing! Thought you could not use arrays in foreach, so never really tried to do that, but had it in mind.